# Downcasting to base type of vector of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, polymorphism, shared-ptr

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    ~Derived() = default;
    int f() override { return 0; }
};

int main() {

const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Base>> vec{std::make_shared<const Derived>()};

}
```

failed at compile time, then at link time, when I originally posted it here with two mistakes in the code.

Too late to delete; no way to revert to the initial form. Hence let it stay as a minimal example to demonstrate that a vector of a `shared_ptr` can have a polymorphic base type.

I have seen other questions touching this topic, with answers suggesting we need a pure virtual base class. Hence the virtual destructor and the pure virtual function in the above minimal example.

Comment: Voting to close as typo: https://godbolt.org/z/4eThTedq8 note `std::vector<int> vec = 1;` will not work too.

Comment: @MarekR it's rather initialisation syntax misconception, than a typo

Comment: You can't assign shared_ptr to a vector.

Comment: After correcting typo in vector initialization, it compiles, but fails to link.

Comment: After supplying an implementation of `Derived::f`, it compiles, links, and executes. - Sorry for messing up with too hasty edits of the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with having a polymorphic type here, but you need to explicitly say that `std::make_shared<const Derived>()` is supposed to be an element, and not an argument of some fancy constructor.

`std::vector` [doesn't have any constructor that takes a single `std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), but you can redirect the name lookup with use of curly braces initialisation syntax (it gives priority to `std::initialiser_list` constructors, and treats the enclosed objects as elements):

```cpp
const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Base>> vec{ std::make_shared<const Derived>(); }
```

Comment: This of course I meant, sorry. Now it fails at link time.

Comment: And after providing an implementation of `Derived::f`, it compiles and executes.